# Row border hidden by background?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-virtualized

```js
feed_page: {
    margin: 'auto'
  },

  feed_list: {
    margin: 'auto'
  },

  feed_item: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderBottom: '1px solid #e0e0e0',
    margin: '10px'
  }
  // ...
  <
  div style = {
    this.stylesheet.feed_page
  } >
  <
  List style = {
    this.stylesheet.feed_list
  }
height = {
  1400
}
rowCount = {
  this.testPosts.length
}
rowHeight = {
  50
}
width = {
  800
}
rowRenderer = {
  this.b_listItemRender
}
/> <
/div>

listItemRender({
  index, // Index of row
  isScrolling, // The List is currently being scrolled
  isVisible, // This row is visible within the List (eg it is not an    overscanned row)
  key, // Unique key within array of rendered rows
  parent, // Reference to the parent List (instance)
  style
}) {
  style = {
    ...style,
    ...this.stylesheet.feed_item
  }

  return ( <
    div key = {
      key
    }
    style = {
      style
    } > {
      this.testPosts[index]
    } <
    /div>
  );
}
```

which results in (i manually turned off the background for 1 row):

[image: css mess]

Two issues:

1. The margin between rows is not being respected
2. The borderBottom is rendering behind the background of the next row item, if i move the next row item down manually by 1px OR set the style to have a height of 49px it shows up.

What did i mess up? I need there to be a space between row elements and each to have a border

Comment: could you make a working snippet from the rendered html...?

Comment: height = height of the content. (Borders and padding are not included in the calculation.) , hence height of element is 50 + border bottom 1px , so next element has to start at top 51 and third element top 102 px (51+51) - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YaXVox

Comment: that's disappointing, i didn't want to have to have to deal with off-by-one logic everywhere. What about the margin?

Comment: @StephenEckels, i have codepen and post, margin px has to be included as well for spacing

Comment: @update option2 to achieve expected result in simple way. Hope it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Margin - to appear, include margin px to the top of next element for spacing

   First Element - top 50px
   second Element - top 50px + 1px border + 10px margin = 61px;
   third element  - 61 + 51 + 10px margin = 122px
2. Height = height of the content. (Borders and padding are not included in the calculation.) ,   hence height of element is 50 + border bottom 1px ,   so next element has to start at top 51 and third element top 102 px (51+51)

[image]

code sample- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YaXVox

```html
<div style="width:auto;height:250px;max-width:800px;max-height:250px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;border:1px solid blue;">
  <div style="width:100%;height:50px;max-width:800px;max-height:250px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;margin:10px;border-bottom:1px solid black;background-color:red">i'm a post</div>
  
  <div style="width:100%;height:50px;max-width:800px;max-height:250px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:61px;margin:10px;border-bottom:1px solid black;background-color:red">i'm a second post</div>
  
  <div style="width:100%;height:50px;max-width:800px;max-height:250px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:122px;margin:10px;border-bottom:1px solid black;background-color:red">i'm third post</div>
</div>
```

**Option 2:**
Other option to resolve is to create class with below CSS,

```
.row{
width:100%;
height:50px;
max-width:800px;
max-height:250px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:10px;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
background-color:red
}
```

**Explanation:**

Remove position absolute and top , then only margin will take case of spacing and border-bottom

code sample for option 2 - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aYOwNm?editors=1100

```css
.row{
width:100%;
height:50px;
max-width:800px;
max-height:250px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:10px;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
background-color:red
}
```

```html
<div style="width:auto;height:250px;max-width:800px;max-height:250px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;border:1px solid blue;">
  <div class="row">i'm a post</div>
  
  <div class="row">i'm a second post</div>
  
  <div class="row">i'm third post</div>
</div>
```